# Ios data leakage security error on https protocol

Tags: ios, security, https

I am facing the issue of data leakage security error in ios app on sending data over https protocol. Should we send the data to encrypt? But https send data in the encrypted format. Do we need to send data back into encrypted format. But this issue is not coming with Android and web app.

```
func callLoginPostAPI(){
    let param:[String:Any] = ["email":"\(txtFieldUsername.text!)","password":"\(txtFieldPassword.text!)"]
    print(param)
    WebServiceHelper.sharedInstance.loginWithDetails(param)
    { (isSuccess, result) in

        if isSuccess == false{
            print("error")
        }
        else {
            print("Success")
            let dict = result as! [String:Any]
            print(dict)

            if(Constant.statusCode==200)
            {
                   Constant.userToken=dict["auth_token"] as! String
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let token = CommonMethods.nullToNil(dict["auth_token"])
                        if let t = token{
                            let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard
                            userDefault.set("\(t)", forKey: Constant.tknKey)
                            Constant.userToken = "\(t)"
                            print(Constant.userToken)
                            userDefault.synchronize()
                            self.callUserProfile()
                        }
}
```

Comment: please share the code how you sending the data?

Comment: it is normal post request on https url , with json data.

Comment: please share the code for better description of your question.

Comment: @MRizwan33 added the code. Please take a view.

Comment: You should store the token in the keychain, not in `UserDefaults`. If you do use user defaults, calling `synchronize` is unnecessary.  Where is the leak supposed to be? What does `loginWithDetails` do?  Are the parameters passed in URL or POSTed?

Comment: okk thanks. let me try this.

Comment: more, please answer the question asked by @Paulw11.

Comment: not able to click @Paulw11.

Comment: @Paulw11 it is a post request  to login user. json data is containing in the username and password.

Comment: Then I can't see a problem with the code you have here apart from the `print(param)`.  You need to provide more information on the issue that has been identified.

Comment: @Paulw11  we are resolving the security issue, in the app scan it is raising the error the data leakage.

Comment: I understand that, but you need information as to *why* the scan thinks that there is a data leakage issue.  From what I can see, apart from the debug print statement, there isn't one.  If you aren't using certificate pinning then you may be vulnerable to a man-in-the-middle attack, but that isn't unique to iOS.

Comment: @Paulw11 We have also error of certificate pinning, can you tell me the what 's is reason for that? Is this is something from server side. Most probably it should not be, because in android and web app scan there is no error of certificate pining, it is only coming in ios.

Comment: Certificate pinning is when your code checks that the SSL certificate of the server it has connected to is what it expects; you typically check the certificate fingerprint.  That way if a man-in-the-middle injects uses a different certificate to spoof your server, your app rejects the connection.  I can't tell you why your tool doesn't flag this on Android.  Maybe it doesn't check.  Maybe the settings are different.  You need to understand what the scan tool is looking for and analyse what it is telling you. You can't just point the tool at the code and hope for the best.

Comment: @Paulw11 one more fever, do we need send the data in encoded format, somewhere i read the send data in encoded format it will resolve your error. But i think https do that it self, so we don't need to send the data in encrypted format.

Comment: You could hash the password, but that doesn't protect you from a replay attack or a man-in-the-middle attack.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168699/discussion-between-aman-kumar-and-paulw11).